# Automatically clear cache of all major browsers installed

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer

I would like a way to clear cache from all my locally installed browsers - quickly and easily.
A simple utility that would ask "Clear all browser caches?" with Yes/No. 
Just the major browsers -IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and optionally Opera

I understand CCleaner can do this but it is not as simple as I would like (as it has other functions as well).

I tried googling/stacking and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CCleaner has an /AUTO switch it accepts via the command line.](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters)  You can then setup CCleaner once with the proper options, and then create a shortcut which invokes CCleaner with the /AUTO switch for one-click operation.

If you want a confirmation dialog, it's not very difficult to create a .vbs script that provides one and then invokes "CCleaner.exe /AUTO" if "Yes" is selected.

Comment: You were faster than me in posting this. I'd only add that you can send this command using a batch script, or you can use iexpress.exe to package the ccleaner.exe and a bat file calling it with /auto into an executable that will extract itself and run the command on execution. I use both these implementations in my current setup.

Comment: I saw the command line options but there wasn't a way to specify exactly what to clear. The need for complete automation is because I wanted to distribute this to a QA team. Can the settings be stored in an ini file and packaged as well? @music2myears - what's iexpress.exe?

Comment: I looked it up - I started with portable version and it stores all settings in an ini which can be packaged up as well. Thanks guys!

Comment: one thing to note - iexpress doesn't allow vbs files to be used as what to run during/after install

Answer (score 1):

The answer is being provided. However, I have alternate way. If you're using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, you can use this extension [Click & Clean [Google Chrome]](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod) or this addon [Click & Clean [Mozilla Firefox]](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clickclean/)

It does provide options to remove history, cache, cookies from other browsers as well and not the only browser you are using. It's quite easy to install and configure without generating any scripts.

PS: A solution for the lazy ones ;)

Comment: good options for sure. But for modern web dev, all 4 browsers should be tested against. My laziness = do a bit more work upfront, click 1 button later. :)